# Magento 2 - Create simple module

Tags: magento2, php, module, javascript, extensions

I try to learn how to create a simple module in Magento 2. I create one but I have a lot of errors. If anyone can help me with a sample. How I can create a simple Magento2 module. This module must have the following:

```
1. to have layout folder (I want to call a custom javascript file that require jquery);
2. template folder (I want to add a phtml file);
3. to have enable / disable option in the admin panel;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Some Helpful Links**

1) Magento 2 Module Creator

https://github.com/darshanb87/magento2-module-creator

2) Hello World Simple module in Magento 2

https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-create-hello-world-module-magento-2.html

OR

http://inchoo.net/magento-2/how-to-create-a-basic-module-in-magento-2/

**For Adding jQuery**

put your jQuery files inside `web/js` folder and add **requirejs-config.js** file

```
var config = {
    'map': {
        '*': {
            loader: 'Vendor_Module/js/jquery.loader',
            menu: 'Vendor_Module/js/jquery.menu'
        }
    }
};
```

For **Enable/Disable** - create **system.xml** file in below location

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="test" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Module</label>
            <tab>general</tab>
            <resource>Vendor_Module::config_notes</resource>
            <group id="view" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Module View Settings</label>
                <field id="enabled" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enable Module On Frontend</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Backend\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Comment: the problem here is that I add in my module layout folder default.xml file, and I call the js and css files there but my js file is in front of jquery and this is jquery dependent, for that I ask for a working module with my requirements

Comment: check my updated answer to add and load jQuery files

Comment: Thanks and how I can call the phtml file? and how I can add that enable / disable admin function?

Comment: I already do this what you told me with the requirejs-config but my files in luma theme for example are in the front of all

Comment: please update your question with what you want and problem you are facing

Comment: so I already write there what I want - a module that will have: layout, template folders and enable / disable function in the admin panel